# Cordova geolocation not working on Android

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, cordova-3

I want to use geolocation on Android. I write app in Apache Cordova.
Geolocation do not work both on andoid pc emulator and andoid phone.

I try http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.getCurrentPosition_full_example 
and http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

My platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="net.example.test" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Test" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

www/config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="net.example.test" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Test</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

I have cordova 3.3.1 and these plugins:

```
$ cordova -v
3.3.1-0.4.2
$ cordova plugin ls
[ 'org.apache.cordova.console',
  'org.apache.cordova.device',
  'org.apache.cordova.dialogs',
  'org.apache.cordova.geolocation' ]
$
```

I find a lot of question on the Internet (on stackoverflow too), but all did not work :-(

Do you have any idea, where I have an error?

---

Update:

Now I have in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log('in onDeviceReady()');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    function onSuccess(position) {
        console.log('in onSuccess()');
        console.log(position.coords.latitude);
        console.log(position.coords.longitude);
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                            'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                            'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                            'Timestamp: '          + position.timestamp                    + '<br />';
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    function onError(error) {
        console.log('in onError()');
        console.log(error.code);
        console.log(error.message);
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    </script>
  </head><body><p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p></body></html>
```

After I run app in Android emulator and run logcat, I see:

```
$ telnet localhost 5554
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
geo fix 50.60 10.20
OK

$ adb logcat Cordova:* DroidGap:* CordovaLog:* *:S
- waiting for device -
I/CordovaLog(  805): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
I/CordovaLog(  805): Found start page location: index.html
I/CordovaLog(  805): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
I/CordovaLog(  805): Found start page location: index.html
D/CordovaLog(  805): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 11 : in onDeviceReady()
D/CordovaLog(  805): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 33 : in onError()
D/CordovaLog(  805): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 34 : null
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Why are you looking at documentation for cordova 2.4 if you're using cordova 3.3? And also you don't say what problem you have (errors in the console? just don't get position?)

Comment: I send bad link. I try code for 3.3.0 version (code is the same as for 2.4) http://goo.gl/8Z4NmH .
I do not see no error or debug messages. My app write "Finding location..." to screen and next nothing happen. 
I add "console.log('Test log');" to my app, but on "adb logcat" output I do not see it.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem. Me too getting the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Well ,  I struggled with that problem for hours (maybe days) and figured out the following link ;
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5977

I am not sure if it is already or going to be deprecated though.
But anyways,  my solution was to "rm org.apache.cordova.geolocation "   because it was not working at all.

Then I came across with the following link of mozilla ;https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

and the only thing that I was doing in order to get the location of the user is the following;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Device Properties Example</title>

</head>
<body>

<script src="http://192.168.43.15:8081/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

 function geo_success(position) {
   alert("success" + " :  " + position.coords.latitude + ",  position.coords.longitude");
  //do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
}

function geo_error() {
alert("Sorry, no position available.");
}

var geo_options = {
enableHighAccuracy: true, 
maximumAge        : 30000, 
timeout           : 27000
}; 

var wpid = navigator.geolocation.getPosition(geo_success, geo_error, geo_options);
</script>
<p id="geolocation">Finding geolocationsss...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE : It did work on phonegapDevApp wirelessy but did not work on real device . That's why I kept looking and learnt in a painful way that js files should be inside body not header , and replaced my navigator.geolocation.getPosition command from "initialize" to above "initialize" . And then added the geolocation plugin again !

Yes finally, my app worked perfectly. It showed the map with my current location pinned in the start up of my app.

Hopefully it works for you too !

Comment: setting the `geo_options.timeout` did the trick for me. thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

I had issue on android before  with cordova-plugin-geolocation latest verions.
Try below version

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="2.4.3" />
```