# Visual Studio Android emulator and Location changes with Apache Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, geolocation, visual-studio-cordova

I am developing a Cordova application in Visual Studio and am using the latest versions of the Tools for Apache Cordova.

I am having problems with the VS Emulator and the Location section of the Additional Tools.

I have added a bunch of geo points and have them automatically cycle through the list but the geolocation plugin downloaded from [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) doesn't pick up on it.

I have also tried it running on iOS where you can choose some predefined scenarios (run, cycle, freeway ride) and it's working as expected there.

Is there something I need to tick off/enable/whatever in order to have the plugin work on the emulator on Android as well?

EDIT:
Here is a piece of code I use to check for location changes:

```
 var watchPosition = function(success, error) {
    watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, { timeout: 30000 });
};
```

This works fine in the iOS emulator but doesn't work in the VS Android Emulator
It even works OK-ish in Ripple (it takes sometimes up to 10-15 seconds for a location change to register)

Comment: Could you post some codes about how you use the plugin?

Comment: @ElvisXia I have added a piece of code but since it's basically a copy paste from the docs it won't be of much use

Comment: Did you enable the geolocation service? Sounds like a dumb question, but to be sure...

Comment: Yes... it's turned on... checked it but this turned out to be just another dead end

Comment: did you try this link [sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819774/cordova-geolocation-not-working-on-android)? Best Regards.

Comment: @Cenk give you good direction I would say. Try it on real device or use some other emulator(I am using this one it is great https://www.genymotion.com/) to be sure it is working after all on Android, because plugin itself can be outdated for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your tries but in the end it turned out to have a lot simpler (and more frustrating?) solution.

I was reading again through the docs for the geolocation plugin and read about a option called `enableHighAccuracy`

I gave it a try and my `watchPosition` function now looks like this

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { 
    timeout: 30000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true 
});
```

And now it works like a charm. Hope this will help someone else in need :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try clearing your Cordova Cache. 
In VS: **Tools**->**Options**, Tools for Apache Cordova, and Clear Cordova Cache.

You could also try clearing the Chrome user directory that Ripple uses, just in case there's a cookie set that's breaking the cordova plugin. You can do so by deleting this folder: %AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\RPL_UserData

I can also recommend you update your VS Tools for Apache Cordova to the latest version from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/cordova-vs.aspx)

In addition, you can try this toturial - I'm not sure if it helps but worth the try - http://docs.telerik.com/platform/samples/Sample-Geolocation/

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different Emulator.  The Emulators provided by VS tend not work correctly in some situaions so download an external Android emulator from another provider than VS.

I recommnd a Genymotion Android Emulator- Easy to use and fairly quick to load: https://www.genymotion.com

Video tutorial on how to use Genymotion with Visual Studio here:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imDT6hIyKc4